# How to get last query id in a Snowflake transaction

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

This is about Snowflake database.

I want to know if there is a way to get the last query id in current transaction.
I have a SQL stored procedure with a couple of delete and insert steps. In the beginning of the procedure, I start a transaction and I commit it at the end if no errors occur.
But to be certain that the procedure calculated the result and inserted some new rows in results table, I want to use the query id with `result_scan` to get the actual number of rows inserted.
I create a Snowflake connection from Python code and parallelly call stored proc with different input parameters.

The function `last_query_id` works at the session level, so it might return the query id from other parallel stored proc execution. For sequential execution, it works fine. But for multiple parallel executions this results in unexpected behavior.
I have also looked at the QUERY_HISTORY* functions but I don't see a relation between query history based on transaction id. There are only options to find queries for user/session etc.

Comment: What language is your stored procedure written in?

Comment: @NickW: Language is Snowflake SQL. Edited the question to indicate the same.

Comment: You can tag your query and filter using that from the query history table (user level)

Answer (score 2):

In SQL Script stored procedures, there is a global variable named `SQLID` that holds the query ID of the last executed query in the procedure.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowflake-scripting/query-id.html#getting-the-query-id-of-the-last-query

```
execute immediate $$
declare
  query_id_1 varchar;
  query_id_2 varchar;
begin
  select 1;
  query_id_1 := sqlid;
  select 2;
  query_id_2 := sqlid;
  return [query_id_1, query_id_2];
end;
$$
;
```